# CSS Nav overflows container

Tags: html, css

I have a css navigation that is not responding the the container. In the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8ngs460s/4/) Everything is working fine. When I put it on the website [here](http://nextmail.email/testing/) the mobile menu drop down link goes to the top right of the wrapper and doesn't stay in the container. If you shrink the screen you will see. Currently on the website it is outside of the header section as I thought there might have been conflicting code. Thanks

CSS

```
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: $nav-background;
  height: $nav-height;
  width: $nav-height;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: $breakpoint) {
  // Hamburger nav visible on mobile only
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
   width: 100%;
    padding: $nav-height 0 15px;
    ul {
      display: none;
      li {
        float: none;
        a {
          padding: 15px;
          line-height: 20px;
        }
        ul li a {
          padding-left: 30px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
  span,
  span:before,
  span:after {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: $nav-font-color;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  }
  span:before {
    top: -10px;
  }
  span:after {
    bottom: -10px;
  }
  &.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
    &:before,
    &:after {
      top: 0;
    }
    &:before {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    &:after {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @cowanjt helped alot before. Any advice?

Comment: I changed the nav sandwich CSS to `position: relative;
top: -70px;
left: 75%;` and it looks good. Of course you might want to edit that, but give it a try.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, if you add something on top of the nav bar, like a title, same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below css in the `nav` tag

```
// Navigation 
nav {
  position: relative;
```

Comment: If anything, that code should replace the already present `absolute` value. Have you tried this? Please a working JSFiddle if so.

Comment: You can simply click on save and post the link here.

Comment: To me, it looks like the nav box is higher than the rest of the navbar

Comment: Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: Chrome: Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit). Safari: Version 11.0 (13604.1.38.1.6)

Comment: Just updated Chrome: Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit). Still shows that.

Answer (score 0):

All the code you are showing here works. The absolute positioning sets up the "hamburger" button within it's closest parent that has position `absolute` or `relative`. In both your fiddle and the website, that is basically the whole body, so the element is positioned in the upper right.

What you want on the website is positioning with respect to the navbar. You need to add `position: relative` to your `<nav>` or your `.nav-container` for the result you want. Then the `top` and `left` properties you add will position your button in that container.